# Severity: Warning failed to open stream: Permission denied Filename: core/Loader.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following error :

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: include(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/caretech/application/views/request_form.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 833

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'application/views/request_form.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/pear')

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 833
```

When I run the following script : http://domainname.com/caretech/transactions/view_request  on my browser. What could be the cause of the above error? How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the user your web server (actually PHP, but in you case that is run by Apache in the form of an extension) is running as does not have permissions to open the file in question. Check the permissions and change them accordingly and you should most likley be good to go.